# Event not working inside table-layout-panel vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, events

[image: Snapshot]

In my Todo App i bind each of my todo and its respective trash button (which is actually picture-box) in a table-layout-panel. I got confused how to delete its respective table-layout-panel when i click on the trash icon as the trash icons click event is not fired.
My Code

```
' On Form Load Event
For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf c Is PictureBox Then
        AddHandler c.Click, AddressOf core.DeleteHandler
    End If
Next c

Public Sub DeleteHandler(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MsgBox("Wow, It Worked!")
End Sub
```

Comment: You should [learn to debug](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), i.e. set breakpoints and step through code to examine variables and other expressions. Had you done so here, you'd have seen that you weren't registering any event handlers. You may not have been able to figure out how to fix that but it would have been a step closer and more information that you could provide to us.

Comment: Sir please let me know how to fix that please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not attaching any event handlers, which you'd have seen if you had debugged your code.  You're looping through the `Controls` collection of the form, which does not include your `PictureBoxes` because they are in the `Controls` collection of the `TableLayoutPanel`.

Comment: Then sir how to loop over them because those table layout panels are dynamically generated?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether they are dynamically generated or not. They're still in the `Controls` collection of the `TableLayoutPanel` so just loop over that instead of the form's `Controls` collection.